# make an ajax call when radio buttons are clicked and update the model value with response in angular

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to find out how to do make an ajax call and set the '$scope.ticker' model with the response in angular. Basically, this is doing an ajax call to get the last price of the ticker (btc_usd, btc_eur, or btc_rur).

Such that "$scope.last" is always the last price of whichever ticker radio button is selected.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="currency" value="btc_usd" ng-model="currency"> USD</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="currency" value="btc_eur" ng-model="currency"> EUR</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="currency" value="btc_rur" ng-model="currency"> RUR</label>


$scope.ticker = quote.ticker($scope.currency).then(function(data){
    var last = data.ticker.last;

    $log.log('last', last);
    $scope.ticker = last;
    $scope.last = last;
});

app.factory('quote', function($http, $log) {
    return {
        ticker: function(currency){
            $log.log('ticker.currency', currency);
            //return the promise directly.
            return $http.get('/api/last/'+currency)
                .then(function(result) {
                    //resolve the promise as the data
                    return result.data;
                });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: could use `ng-change` on radios, or `$scope.$watch('currency'` to trigger your ajax call

Comment: how would i trigger the ajax call from the $watch?

Comment: call your code within callback of $watch   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watch

Answer (score 2):

First all I would change `ng-model` to `ng-model="$parent.currency"`.

Second - we can write radios with `ng-repeat:`

HTML:

```
 <label ng-repeat="value in list">
       <input type="radio" name="currency" ng-model="$parent.currency" ng-value="value.name" />{{value.name}}
      </label>
```

when controller:

```
 $scope.list = [{
    name: "USD"
}, {
    name: "EUR"
}, {
    name: "RUR"
}];

$scope.currency = 'USD';

$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.currency;
},

function (newValue, oldValue) {        
    console.log(newValue);
}, true);
```

Now from `$watch` you can run ajax request based on `newValue`

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/736/)**</kbd>